# Override global function to mock in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm making a small sized test library, and have a question. How to mock a function defined at the top level? See the full source code in a single file.

```js
function main(){
  var users = getUsers();
  // ...
}

function getUsers() {
  var data = getData()
  // ...
}

function getData() {
  // ... get data from database
}



// test code

function mock_getData() {
  return [{id: 0, name: 'Alice'}, {id: 1, name: 'Bob'}]
}

test('getUsers', function(){
  var users = getUsers()  // HOW TO CALL mock_getData instead of getData in getUsers ?
  myAssert(users[0]['name'], 'Alice')
  myAssert(users[1]['name'], 'Bob')
})

// my very small test library
var tests = []

function myAssert(a, b) {
  if (a !== b) { throw new Error()}
}

function test(name, func) {
  tests.push({name: name, func: func})
}

function runTests() {
  for (i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
    var current_test = tests[i]
    try {
      current_test.func()
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(current_test.name)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Jest or something similar? Or do you plan to create your own version of `jest.mock`?

Comment: @nickzoum Thanks for the comment. No I'm not using any test library like jest. I'm gonna make very small version of jest for just my use. (Btw I'm making an app on Google App Script and it seems difficult to run jest. So I'll make something similar. It is also from my technical interest).

Comment: A "simple" approach would be to use `Object.defineProperty` on `global` or the `module` you're using and override the original function/value, you probably want to keep a reference to the original so that you can reset it when you need to unmock. (might be a good idea to check jest source code on github for inspiration)

Comment: @nickzoum Thanks. I think I can go right direction. I've found it is used in`jest.mock`. I'll work on it :D

Answer (score 0):

Just use function expressions rather than declarations.

For example you can set one global var _DEBUG declared somewhere at the beginning of your code like:

`var _DEBUG = false`

then you have something like this:

```
// this is function expression so due to hoisting 
// it won't be defined/loaded until called 

var getData = function() {
   ...get data from database
}
```

then somewhere else you can simply do this:

```
//keep all your overrides nicely in one place

if(_DEBUG == true){

  //override the original function with this one, the good thing is that you keep the name exactly the same 

  getData = function(){
     return [{id: 0, name: 'Alice'}, {id: 1, name: 'Bob'}]
  }

}

///_DEBUG = true //comment-uncomment this to have your test code working
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your runtime is browser, toplevel functions sits in the window object.

```js
//--- main.js
function getData(){
    return "getData";
}

//--- test.js

const originalGetData = getData;

function mock(){
    window.getData = function(){ return "mockData"}
}

function tearDown(){
    window.getData = originalGetData;
}

function log(){
    console.log(getData(), window.getData(), getData === window.getData);
}

log(); // getData getData true
mock();
log(); // mockData mockData true
tearDown(); 
log(); // getData getData true
```

Same reasoning can be used if the function is not at top level, you will need to alter the given scope/module.

If your services are classes/scopes, you can also use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).